# How can I forecast Gini using ML?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, econometrics, gini

I have a data set containing 20 years of Gini values ​​for a country. The latest data are for 2018. I want to predict the Gini values ​​for this country by 2025. How can I do this using ML techniques? Also, which econometric forecast model would you recommend?

Comment: You have a time series, better to look into methods for time series prediction (or forecasting). Search this site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing you should do is try an extremely simple forecasting benchmark, like the exponential smoothing model that is automatically selected by `forecast::ets()`. I recommend the excellent free online book [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/).

After you have calculated this benchmark, which should take about ten minutes, you can go into econometric forecasting, putting all other macroeconometric variables into a giant vector autoregression (VAE). There are many textbooks on econometrics. This second step shouldn't take much more than a year.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kolasa. The book was useful to understanding the basics of forecasting. It has also a chapter about how we can forecast with ML techniques. Thank you for your benchmark suggestion, it'll be my first step.